# Boost regex don't match tabs

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm using boost regex_match and I have a problem with matching no tab characters.
My test application looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_regex.hpp>

int
main(int args, char** argv)
{
  boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;

  if(args == 3) {
    std::string text(argv[1]);
    boost::regex expression(argv[2]);

    std::cout << "Text : " << text << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Regex: " << expression << std::endl;

    if(boost::regex_match(text, what, expression, boost::match_default) != 0) {
        int i = 0;

        std::cout << text;

        if(what[0].matched)
          std::cout << " matches with regex pattern!" << std::endl;
        else
          std::cout << " does not match with regex pattern!" << std::endl;

        for(boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>::const_iterator     it=what.begin(); it!=what.end(); ++it) {
          std::cout << "[" << (i++) << "] " << it->str() << std::endl;
        }
      } else {
        std::cout << "Expression does not match!" << std::endl;
      }
  } else {
    std::cout << "Usage: $> ./boost-regex <text> <regex>" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I run the program with these arguments, I don't get the expected result:

```
$> ./boost-regex "`cat file`" "(?=.*[^\t]).*"
Text : This     text includes    some   tabulators
Regex: (?=.*[^\t]).*
This    text includes    some   tabulators matches with regex pattern!
[0] This        text includes    some   tabulators
```

In this case I would have expected that *what[0].matched* is false, but it's not.

Is there any mistake in my regular expression?
Or do I have to use other format/match flag?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The actual text you give to the program doesn't have any tabs, as you can see in the output (it shows the text "\t" instead of printing an actual tab).

Comment: This is correct, I only wanted to show a short example! I'm using a text file including tabs (validated with hexdump -> 0x09). I have corrected my example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do. My understanding is, you want the regex to fail as soon as there is a tab in the text.

Your positive lookahead assertion `(?=.*[^\t])` is true as soon as it finds a non tab, and there are a lot of non tabs in your text.

If you want it to fail, when there is a tab, go the other way round and use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?!.*\t).*
```

this assertion will fail as soon as it find a tab.